# How to test methods in models when using Sinatra?

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, tdd, sinatra

I have a project that is using Sinatra framework.

How do I test methods in my models, or controllers that do not have web services but have to use DB connection?

Any link with github/ or Google would be great, as I can't find anything useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do functional tests of your Sinatra endpoints as outlined here:

- http://www.sinatrarb.com/testing.html
- http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ruby/how-to-integrate-rspec-into-a-sinatra-app/

And as for your models, just unit test them like normal with a unit test framework:

- http://www.rubyinside.com/a-minitestspec-tutorial-elegant-spec-style-testing-that-comes-with-ruby-5354.html
- http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ruby/ruby-for-newbies-testing-with-rspec/
- http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/an-introduction-to-rspec

If you're not familiar with testing at all, I'd recommend digging into a book:

- [The RSpec Book: Behaviour Driven Development with RSpec, Cucumber, and Friends](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1934356379)
- http://artofunittesting.com/other-books/